# Checking for exitence or counting files with a pattern and without a pattern

Tags: c#, linq, file

In later version of .NET, there's a neat way to check the number or existence of files with names that follow a pattern.

```
private int HowManyDonkeys(string path)
{
  return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*donkey*");
}

private bool AreThereAnyDonkeys(string path)
{
  return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*donkey*").Any();
}
```

However, I wonder how to turn it around and list the files that **are not** donkeys. One way to do it is to list all and subtract the number of unwanted ones but it's not so neat. Another way is to use LINQ and go like this.

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*")
  .Count(name => name.Contains("anti-donkey"));

Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*")
  .Any(name => name.Contains("anti-donkey"));
```

Is there an even better way (i.e. one that let's me specify the filtering condition for the pattern **as the opposite** of the input?

Comment: @Sybren I can use *Any()* and *Count*, as the examples show, which eliminates the point of doing *Where()* first. But that's not the question - I wish to know i fI can specify an anti-pattern in the enumerating method.

Comment: @Kondrad Viltersten use `!` operator

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` only allows simple DOS search (* and ?), no regex.

Comment: @Sybren Can you show an example on how to use the negation operator, please? Also, please note my comment on the LINQ part.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without `LINQ`?

Comment: @RichardSchneider Darn... You should post it as a reply. Seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: @Sybren You're missing the point. I'm doing it with LINQ now. I wanted to know if there was a neater way. The question I'm asking is not "how-to". It's "how-to-even-better". Apparently, it's not possible...

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, it's not possible indeed the way you're doing it with `LINQ` seems very neat to me already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumerateFiles` only allows simple DOS search (* and ?), no regex.

As other's have said, You could use LINQ but that is not your question.

Answer (score 1):

Get the files:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\").Where(x => !x.Contains("donkey")).ToList();
```

Get the count

```
int count= Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\").Count(x => !x.Contains("donkey"));
```

Comment: Not to be harsh but this is not right. First of all, you complicate things by adding *Where()* needlessly. Second of all, I'm giving a better example of LINQ in my question already. Lastly, it doesn't answer **my** question - it's about specifying an anti-pattern **without** using LINQ. If at all possible. Also, *ToList()* is plain unnecessary there. And the type is *IEnumerable<string>*, which gets lost from view because the method's name is enumerating **files**. Poorly chosen name, to be honest.

Comment: you can use Expression.Not(callExpression).

Comment: You might want to give an example. I'm not familiar with the class *Expression*. Is that a 3rd party tool? My VS didn't recognized it... Or are you still referring to LINQ and the method *Not*?

Comment: Its under System.LINQ.Expressions, where you can define a expression for the match & then use Not() to have anti matches. Not so popular i guess & didnt have enough knowlenge on that but if you could take a look at -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276485/c-sharp-expression-using-and-or-and-not-expression-together-based-on-ast and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047(v=vs.110).aspx